# powershell message dependant on multiple array match

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to develop a script to move (some) files arriving in a directory and log the results. I have the copying part right(I say right - it works - but it could in fact be hopelessly wrong!), but not the logging.

Here's the command line:

> PCopy.ps1 -carrier ECM -direction IN -filter DEL, MAN

The first parameter correctly ascertains the directories, the second chooses the sub directory. The third parameter is where it gets interesting, as this is an array.

So what I have come up with is a couple of nested loops:

```
Foreach($item in $filter){
    foreach($File in $filenames){
        If($File -match $Item){ 
    Write-Log "$File matches filter" -Path $LogFile
    Copy-Item -Path $Sourcefile\$direction\$File -Destination $Destination
```

This is fine. But because it loops through each filter, and file, a file that matches one filter , doesn't necessarily match the next one.

I am trying to copy the files I need, and log only, the details of the files I don't need.

So let's say 3 files arrive

```
Man.txt
Del.txt
Ava.txt
```

I want the log file to show that the first two match a filter - and copy them to the destination, but the third one doesn't match any filter so is being logged, and not copied.

I know that the way I have written it, as each file is compared to the filter - I will get 2 copied messages, and 4 not matched messages - which is not what I want.

I need a more elegant way so something like:

```
Man.txt matches the filter MAN and was copied to $destination
Del.txt matches the filter DEL and was copied to $destination
Ava.txt did not match any filter so is being logged only
```

The only thing I thought of, was to try and build an array of the answers, and check for (and remove) the duplicates - but it doesn't seem very intuitive - can anyone help?

I'm new to Powershell- so forgive me if I have missed the bleedin' obvious!

Comment: the match operator uses regex, so the regex OR symbol will work. you can test for `One or Two` by using `One|Two`. that will let you skip iterating thru the filter items.

Comment: Lee - many thanks for that, Like I say - I'm new at PowerShell. I assume that will work irrespective of the number of arguments in "filter"?

I did resolve the problem by adding the matches to a list, and the non matches to a list, then getting the unique items from the non-matched list - but I knew as I was writing it, it wasn't very elegant!

Comment: you can add as many items to a regex OR list as you want. [*grin*] that will let you filter only ONE time, instead of once per item. you will need to decide if you really want per-item notices, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regex OR to test for 'this OR that' with the '|' symbol. something like this ...

```
$Filter = 'One', 'Two'
$RegexFilter = $Filter -join '|'

'This contains One, but not the other filter item.' -match $RegexFilter
'One and Two are here.' -match $RegexFilter
'This line has only Two.' -match $RegexFilter
'No matching items are in this line.' -match $RegexFilter
```

output ...

```
True
True
True
False
```